# Discord Py bot dms server owner when he joins the server

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, owner, dm

So i want that the bot dms the server owner when it get added to the server.

Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild, ctx):
  guild_owner = client.get_user(int(ctx.guild.owner.id))
  await guild_owner.send("hi")
```

But I always get this one error:

```
TypeError: on_guild_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

I know what that means but i dont know how to fix that.

Comment: The `on_guild_join` function should take only one argument

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as mousetail has said, [`on_guild_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.on_guild_join) only takes one argument. You should only have `guild` as the function's argument. Secondly, since you're using a [`guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.Guild) object, you should already be able to access the guild's owner through `guild.owner`. Do view the revised code below.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    try:
        await guild.owner.send("I'm now in your server!")
    except: # occurs if your bot cannot send dm to the owner
        print(f"{guild.owner} has their dms turned off")
```